# How to search inside json file with redis?

Tags: python, django, redis

Here I set a json object inside a key in a redis. Later I want to perform search on the json file stored in the redis. My search key will always be a json string like in the example below and i want to match this inside the stored json file.

Currently here i am doing this by iterating and comparing but instead i want to do it with redis. How can I do it ?

```
rd = redis.StrictRedis(host="localhost",port=6379, db=0)
if not rd.get("mykey"):
   with open(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "my_file.josn")) as fl:
      data = json.load(fl)
      rd.set("mykey", json.dumps(data))
else:
  key_values = json.loads(rd.get("mykey"))
  search_json_key =  {
          "key":"value",
          "key2": {
            "key": "val"
           }
        }
  # here i am searching by iterating and comparing instead i want to do it with redis
  for i in key_values['all_data']:
     if json.dumps(i) == json.dumps(search_json_key):
        # return 

# mykey format looks like this:
{
    "all_data": [
        {
          "key":"value",
          "key2": {
            "key": "val"
           }
        },
        {
          "key":"value",
          "key2": {
            "key": "val"
           }
        },
        {
          "key":"value",
          "key2": {
            "key": "val"
           }
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: Consider using [RedisJSON](https://redis.io/docs/stack/json/).

Answer (score 1):

To do search with Redis and JSON you have two options - you can use the [FT CREATE](https://redis.io/commands/ft.create/) command to create an index that you can then use [FT SEARCH](https://redis.io/commands/ft.search/) over, (while both of these web pages show the CLI syntax you can do
`rd.ft().create() / search()` in your python script)

OR you can check out the [python OM client](https://github.com/redis/redis-om-python) that will take care of that to some extent for you.

Either way you'll have to do a bit of a rework to fully take advantage of Redis' search capabilities.